# Infinite false limit verification via $N-M$ method

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

> $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{x^3 + 6}{2x^2-5} = +\infty$$

The limit is false. Let's verify it.

By the formal definition, $\forall N > 0, \exists M_N > 0$ such that $\forall x < -M_N$ we have $f(x) > N$. Whence

$$\frac{x^3+6}{2x^2-5} > N$$

To deal with this, I thought about this

$$x^3 + 6 \leq x^3/3$$
$$2x^2 - 5 \leq 2x^2$$

remembering $x \to -\infty$. Hence

$$x > \underbrace{6N}_{M_N}$$

which means using the definition: $$x < -6N$$

But this seems legit, as for $M$ to grow big, $-6N$ grows infinitely negatively big...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: It seems like you can correctly state the formal definition of "$\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = \infty$". The first priority, if you want to prove the opposite, is to be able to correctly negate that formal definition, using logical rules for negating quantifiers and so on. For example, the formal definition starts with "for every $N$", so its negation will start with "there exists $N$ such that". Knowing the logical structure of the statement you're trying to verify (the negation of the limit assertion) is crucial to understanding what constitutes a proof of it.

Comment: @GregMartin So you are saying that I cannot prove the limit doesn't exist via the definition of the existence, but I have to re-state the definition for when it doesn't exist?

Comment: @GregMartin So let me try: "there is a $N > 0$ such that $\forall M_N > 0$ there is a $x < -M_N$ for which we have $f(x) < N$ ?

Comment: "The limit is false" A limit cannot be false or true because it is not a statement. An equality can be false or true.

Comment: My guess is that when you wrote $2x^2+5\leqslant 2x^2$, you meant to write $2x^2-5\leqslant 2x^2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Indeed, edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your approach lies in the fact that from the inequalities$$x^3+6\leqslant\dfrac{x^3}3\tag1$$and$$2x^2-5\leqslant2x^2$$there is nothing that you can deduce about the quotient $\dfrac{x^3+6}{2x^2-5}$. However, from $(1)$ and $2x^2-5\geqslant x^2$ (which holds when $x\notin\left[-\sqrt5,\sqrt5\right]$), you can deduce that$$\frac{x^3+6}{2x^2-5}\leqslant\frac x3.\tag2$$So, and since $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac x3=-\infty$, $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{x^3+6}{2x^2-5}=-\infty$ too. On the other hand, it follows from $(2)$ that$$x<-\sqrt5\implies\dfrac{x^3+6}{2x^2-5}<0,$$and so you cannot possibly have$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{x^3+6}{2x^2-5}=\infty.$$